# Accessing nested objects in javascript d3

Tags: javascript

I have data that looks like this (with multiple countries)

```
[
  {country:"Country1", GDP : 12345, GDPgrowth : {year1:123, year2:234, year3:345}},
  {country:"Country2", GDP : 12345, GDPgrowth : {year1:123, year2:234, year3:345}}
]
```

I am able to access each country's data by using a `forEach` and looping over the "rows".

However, I can't figure out how to access the individual values within `GDPgrowth`. I tried to do a nested `forEach`, but it throws an error about it not being a function, and I think it's because the data within `GDPgrowth` is not an array.  I also tried a generic for loop approach but couldn't seem to achieve what I was looking for.

What is the recommended method for getting into these values (ideally without having to select by name `year1`, `year2`, `year3` each time)?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array with the object values and you can use `forEach()` to iterate over they.

```js
const input = [
    {country: "Country1", GDP: 12345, GDPgrowth: {year1:123, year2:234, year3:345}},
    {country:"Country2", GDP : 12345, GDPgrowth : {year1:123, year2:234, year3:345}}
];

input.forEach(x =>
{
    console.log("country: " + x.country);
    Object.values(x.GDPgrowth).forEach(y => console.log("year: " + y))
});
```

Also, I suggest to read about [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) too.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It's starting to make a little more sense and I'm off to read about Object.keys() and Object.entries().

Comment: @LaurenH you are welcome, consider to accept the answer if this helps you.